# Where is the .idea directory located for Android Studio on mac?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.6

I have encountered a problem in Android Studio and I need to be able to:

1. delete the .idea directory
2. delete all .iml files

I'm not sure of where the .idea directory is located or where the .iml files are stored on mac.

Comment: The .idea directory is a hidden one.  You can find it on your file explorer or the terminal.  I guess you are using Linux or MacOs

Comment: I am running macOS.

Comment: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-

Comment: Is this question solved? There's an answer below but not green check for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The .idea folder is in the top level folder of your project, but it's hidden because it starts with a dot.

You can see it by performing an `ls -a` (for "show *a*ll files") in the Terminal in that folder (Command+Drag the folder into the Terminal to open that folder in the Terminal).

You can also [enable showing hidden files in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/how-can-i-view-hidden-files-in-the-finder).